# No se muestra el contenido de un array con la directiva NgFor en Angular

Tags: angular

Tengo un problema a la hora de mostrar el contenido de un array en HTML

El siguiente array:

```
let descripcion = [
  " m. y f. Mamífero carnívoro doméstico de cabeza re…s cuya pupila se dilata para ver en la oscuridad.",
  "m. Instrumento de hierro que sirve para agarrar fu…os a las cubas, y en el oficio de portaventanero."
]
```

Pero al meter la siguiente línea de código en el HTML no me lo muestra y no sé cual es el problema.

```
<div class="texto" *ngFor= "let i of descripciones">{{ i }}</div>
```

Comment: Agrega el código del componente.

Answer (score 2):

Está mal el nombre de tu arreglo en la directiva `*ngFor`. Lo tienes así

`<div class="texto" *ngFor= "let i of descripciones">{{ i }}</div>`

y debe de ser así

`<div class="texto" *ngFor= "let i of descripcion">{{ i }}</div>`